# SCons: rebuild after clean failed

Tags: build, scons

I'm trying the example: https://bitbucket.org/Anteru/build-systems/src/default/scons/

I modified the `SConstruct` file to set the build directories:

```
SConscript(
    'statlib/SConscript',
    variant_dir='build/statlib',
    duplicate=0
)
SConscript(
    'dynlib/SConscript',
    variant_dir='build/dynlib',
    duplicate=0
)
SConscript(
    'executable/SConscript',
    variant_dir='build/executable',
    duplicate=0
)
```

The first build is successful.

However, build after `scons --clean` and build with `scons --no-cache` failed, cause SCons uses the wrong path of the file `tablegen.py`.

The modified example: [scons.zip](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09076414549427282851)

Comment: Why are you doing "p = os.path.abspath ('./tablegen.py')" in statlib/SConscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your example file statlib/SConscript to:

```
import os

# This is needed so we get the python from PATH
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

env.Append (CPPPATH='#')
pyexec = 'python' if os.name == 'nt' else 'python3'
env.Command ('table.cpp', 'tablegen.py', '{} $SOURCE > $TARGET'.format (pyexec))

env.StaticLibrary('statlib', [
    # This adds fPIC in a portable way
    SharedObject ('StaticLibrarySource.cpp'), 
    SharedObject ('table.cpp')])
```

It should work.

Note: I've filed an issue against the repo you specified.
https://bitbucket.org/Anteru/build-systems/issues/2/youre-statlib-sconscript-has-issue-which